# Why are absolute enthalpies of reactants not available?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

The standard enthalpy of reaction is given as $$\Delta_r H = \sum\nu\;  H_m(\text{products})- \sum\nu\;H_m(\text{reactants}).$$

Peter Atkins in his book *Elements of Physical Chemistry* then writes regarding this equation:

> The problem with this eqn, is that we have **no way of knowing the absolute enthalpies of the substances** . To avoid this problem, we can imagine the reaction as taking place by an *indirect route*, in which the reactants are first broken down into the elements. [...]
>
> With the introduction of standard enthalpies of formation, we can write $$\Delta_r H = \sum\nu\;  \Delta_f H(\text{products})- \sum\nu\;\Delta_f H(\text{reactants}).$$  The first term on the right is the enthalpy of formation of all the products from their elements; the second term on the right is the enthalpy of formation of all the reactants from their elements..the fact that the enthalpy is a state function means that a reaction enthalpy calculated this way is identical to the value that would be calculated from the former eqn, **if absolute enthalpies were available.**

I'm not understanding why we can't calculate the absolute enthalpies. After all, enthalpy of a substance at a certain pressure (which is constant as we are talking about standard state & that is 1 bar) is given by the defining equation:

$$H= U +pV$$.

Yes, can't we calculate the internal energy taking a certain state as the zero of the energy? Why isn't it possible to calculate the absolute enthalpy?

Comment: If you "take a certain state as the zero of the energy", then it is no longer an absolute internal energy, it is a relative internal energy. But I see what you mean. After all entropies are also defined to be 0 at absolute zero and we call those "absolute". I imagine it has more to do with the internal energy of a molecule not being easy to quantify. It is probably possible, but not worth the effort, which makes the values "not available".

Comment: @orthocresol: I do count it as an answer but let the question take some time more to see what others think.

Comment: Nah, it doesn't deserve to be an answer.

Comment: @orthocresol: It's your opinion but your argument has logic, after all.

Comment: Related: [Why it is not possible to find absolute value of internal energy?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/19541/7951)