# Do both H (enthalpy) and ∆H, or ∆H alone have a physical significance?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

My chemistry teacher said that H (enthalpy) alone has no physical significance it is ∆H or change in enthalpy that has a physical significance. But my book says that both have a significance and H alone represents the total heat content of the body. Thus I am in a confusion, please help me.

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19541/why-it-is-not-possible-to-find-absolute-value-of-internal-energy

Answer (score 1):

Offcourse H and ∆H have physical significance. H represents the enthalpy of a system. Enthalpy refers to the sum of the internal energy of a system plus the product of the system's pressure and volume.

The ∆ symbol is used to represent change. Therefore, ∆H represents the change in enthalpy of a system in the reaction. So your book is completely correct.

Comment: That being said, the teacher is right too (in a way). We pretty much never know absolute enthalpy of anything. Arguably, it may not even be well-defined.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I completely agree with  your point.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Ya thats true. Agreed with you